# How to accumulate resolve calls for a single request?

Tags: reactjs, relayjs, graphql, graphql-js

When a `graphql request` hits my server it jumps into several different `resolve functions` depending on the query.
But I don't want to hit my database with sometimes dozens of small requests (basically a `select` in each `resolve` function). That would not really scale very well.

Is there a way to accumulate all these resolve calls for a single graphql request - so that at the end I can do some magic and build only a single `select` to my database and then resolve all promises?

I can see a few ways of building something myself by accumulating all the promises I return in the resolve functions, but I don't know when all resolve functions for a single request have been called.

Is there a solution to this problem? How does Facebook deal with that scenario?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batching all resolve calls into a *single* database query is an active area of exploration for GraphQL implementations and isn't supported in the reference implementation. Instead, we recommend using [dataloader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dataloader#getting-started). Using `dataloader` can help ensure that you fetch each record from the storage layer once, even if it is queried multiple times.

Comment: Thank you. But how do I know that all resolve functions have been called for the current graphql request?

Comment: You generally don't: when all resolve functions have been called, it means the response is fully generated. The reference implementation (and likely most other implementations) process queries using a breadth-first traversal: child fields can't be resolved until the parent record has been resolved.

`dataloader` helps by deduplicating requests for the same object.

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try. I am using sequelize and MySQL at the moment which might not quite fit with dataloader since sequelize does its own entity caching - but not query caching. I will update here once I have a clearer picture.

Comment: Note that it does more than dedupe: it batches all requests in the same "tick". See the readme: "Batching is a not an advanced feature, it's DataLoader's primary feature."